# What is the origin of the (nearly obsolete) term "binary decimal"?

Tags: reference-request, terminology, math-history, number-systems

> What is the origin of the (nearly obsolete) term "binary decimal"?

At least two important publications in the 1930s used this oxymoron to mean what is now ordinarily called a "[base-2 (or binary) numeral](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_notation)":

- A. M. Turing, "On Computable Numbers, with an Application to the Entscheidungsproblem", *Proceedings of the London Mathematical Society*, 2 42 (1): 230–65, 1937:

  > The real number whose expression as a **binary decimal** is obtained by prefacing this sequence by a decimal point is called the *number computed by the machine*. [p. 232]
- G. H. Hardy and E. M. Wright, *An introduction to the theory of numbers* (First ed., 1938), Oxford: Clarendon Press:

  > Any positive integer up to $2^n-1$ inclusive can be expressed uniquely as a **binary decimal** of $n$ figures, i.e., as a sum $\sum_0^{n-1} a_s 2^s$, where every $a_s$ is $0$ or $1$. [p. 115]

**NB-1**: Turing's paper contains the earliest usage of the term "binary decimal" that I've managed to find. In this paper, the frequent use of the term "decimal" — without the qualifier — in reference to base-2 (binary) notation easily misleads a modern reader to think it's referring to base-ten notation. In fact, the opening paragraph states "According to my definition, a number is computable if its decimal can be written down by a machine", but not until the third page does one find that this "decimal" means *binary decimal*. This suggests that in Turing's day, there must already have been some established usage of this oxymoron, and very significant ambiguity in the term "decimal".

**NB-2**: I wrote *nearly* obsolete, because this remains the terminology in the 2008 edition of Hardy & Wright — which also still contains the original footnote "We ignore the verbal contradiction involved in the use of 'decimal'; there is no other convenient word."

Comment: "...use of the term "decimal" in reference to base-2 notation, misleads a modern reader to think it's referring to base-10 notation..." -- In an important sense, it *is* referring to base-10 notation :)

Comment: @ChrisTaylor: I suppose you're referring to '10' as denoting 2. ;) I almost wrote base-ten, but that's usually the presumed meaning of base-10, I think. I've edited it anyway.

Comment: I don't see why "binary decimal" is so terrible. The sense in which one could call it a verbal contradiction is evident, but at the same time the meaning is perfectly clear.

Answer (score 1):

There *is* no other convenient word. A numeral, in English, means a representation of an integer. A decimal, in English, means a number with some digits after the decimal point.

It is far easier to abstract away the ten-ness of "decimal" when necessary than to invent a hitherto unused specialist term and expect readers to understand it easily.

You might compare the fuss over whether it is ever possible to have more than two "alternatives", given that *alter* in Latin implies either-or-ness.

Comment: Possibly there are regional differences, but the term "numeral" is often used for a representation of any number (not necessarily an integer). There is some discussion at [this link](http://mathforum.org/library/drmath/view/58756.html). (BTW, I've seen a few publications in which authors do actually misread the Turing paper and think he was defining computable reals in terms of base-ten digits.)

Comment: When not in base ten, it becomes the *radix*; e.g. "radix point"

Comment: There are indeed convenient words. We may speak of a number's *binary representation*. This is not a hitherto unused term; specialist, perhaps, but surely easily understood by the intended readership. IMO it is not reasonable to expect the reader to abstract away the ten-ness of "decimal", because that ten-ness is explicit.